# RoR condition for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to fetch other than collect value

i used below code

@boys = People.find(:all,:conditions => ["id != ?", @boy_id],:order => "created_at DESC")

where, @boy_id is collection of ids

but its not fetching the values

when i use **IN(?)** it fetches id in collection...

i want to fetch id values which are not in collection.. please suggest contrary to **IN(?)**

Comment: Why did you named you collection of ids "@boy_id"? :)

Comment: For next developer it is better to name it `@boy_ids`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@boys = People.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", @boy_id], :order => "created_at DESC")
```